# Undefined color error in Section after defining the color

Tags: errors, color

In the following MWE,

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,showpacs,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb,superscriptaddress]{revtex4}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % in order to use color names
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{ngreen}{rgb}{0.2,0.7,0.2}%161
\newcommand{\grn}{\color{ngreen}}

\begin{document}

\title{\grn Title}% Force line breaks with \\
\maketitle

\section{\grn Section} % compilation error in this line!
Some Text.

\end{document}
```

I get the compilation error "Package xcolor Error: Undefined color 'NGREEN' ", but it seems to me that I have correctly defined the color ngreen. What's the problem? Note that if you comment the line, I got the correct compilation for the title.

PS I get the same error compiling with latex and pdflatex.

PPS probably some of the packages are redundant.

Comment: I suppose the problem comes with section capitalization: add `\colorlet{NGREEN}{ngreen}` for a workaround.

Comment: With `article` it works just fine.  This must be related to `revtex4`.  I've never used it, so I've no clue...

Comment: You are right @ClaudioFiandrino, adding \colorlet{NGREEN}{ngreen} it works. So the capitalization of the section title reflects to the commands?

Comment: @nickie The guy who has sent me the .tex file used \grn to highlight his changing to the text. Probably it works fine on his laptop. I wonder why it doesn't on mine without \colorlet{NGREEN}{ngreen}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `\protect\grn` or else `\grn` is expanded to `\color{NGREEN}` when the section heading is converted to upper case.

```
\documentclass{revtex4}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{ngreen}{rgb}{0.2,0.7,0.2}%161
\newcommand{\grn}{\color{ngreen}}
\begin{document}
\section{\protect\grn This is a section}
\end{document}
```

This is not specific to `revtex` except in that `revtex` capitalises section headings. To cause the same problem in any document class you can use

```
\MakeUppercase{\grn abc}
```

and the solution (`\protect`) is the same.